# Transclude a mediawiki page's content list to another page

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, transclusion

I wrote a simple book using Mediawiki. It has 10 chapters and a chapter in a page.

I want to create a page named `index`, and make every page's content list in this `index` page.

example: `Python document`

what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

If you put all chapters in subpages, i.e., "Book name/chapter name", then you can transclude Special:Prefixindex: {{Special:Prefixindex/Book name/}}